# Base64 Incorrect padding error using Python

Tags: python, hex, base64

I am trying to decode Base64 into Hex for about 200 Base64 data and I am getting this following error. It does decoding for 60 of them then stops.

```
ABHvPdSaxrhjAWA=
0011ef3dd49ac6b8630160
ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tt.py", line 36, in <module>
    csvlines[0] = csvlines[0].decode("base64").encode("hex")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\base64_codec.py", line 43, in base64_decode
    output = base64.decodestring(input)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 325, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Some original Base64 source from CSV

```
ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABDPdS4xriiAVQ=
ABDPdSqxrizAU4=
ABDPdSrxrjPAUo=
```

Comment: Errors are still text; please copy and paste that text, a screenshot is not searchable.

Comment: It means the source text didn't really come from base64.  Where did you get the text?  Perhaps you made a cut-n-paste error?

Comment: @JohnGordon: no, it could also mean the padding is missing. The padding is not actually mandatory for decoding, it is only helpful if you want to detect an incomplete transmission.

Comment: All your sample strings are 1 padding character short. The one value that worked (above your traceback), had one more character (`v`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the encoded text is missing an `=`, I would be very nervous about simply adding one on to the end.  Obviously the text was altered; how can we be sure the missing character isn't in the middle somewhere?

Comment: @JohnGordon: we can't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have at least one string in your CSV file that is either not a Base64 string, is a corrupted (damaged) Base64 string, or is a string that is missing the required `=` padding. Your example value, `ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=`, is short one `=` *or* is missing another data character.

Base64 strings, properly padded, have a length that is a multiple of 4, so you can easily re-add the padding:

```
value = csvlines[0]
if len(value) % 4:
    # not a multiple of 4, add padding:
    value += '=' * (4 - len(value) % 4) 
csvlines[0] = value.decode("base64").encode("hex")
```

If the value then *still* fails to decode, then your input was corrupted or not valid Base64 to begin with.

For the example error, `ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=`, the above adds one `=` to make it decodable:

```
>>> value = 'ABHPdSaxrhjAWA='
>>> if len(value) % 4:
...     # not a multiple of 4, add padding:
...     value += '=' * (4 - len(value) % 4)
...
>>> value
'ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=='
>>> value.decode('base64')
'\x00\x11\xcfu&\xb1\xae\x18\xc0X'
>>> value.decode('base64').encode('hex')
'0011cf7526b1ae18c058'
```

I need to emphasise that your data may simply be corrupted. Your console output includes one value that worked, and one that failed. The one that worked is *one* character longer, and that's the *only difference*:

```
ABHvPdSaxrhjAWA=
ABHPdSaxrhjAWA=
```

Note the `v` in the 4th place; this is missing from the second example. This could indicate that something happened to your CSV data that caused that character to be dropped from the second example. Adding in padding can make the second value decodable again, but the result would be *wrong*. We can't tell you which of those two options is the cause here.

Comment: I just looked through all the base64 data and it has a = sign. It decodes for 60 of them but then I get that error even though all data seems identical

Comment: @James: but your sample string should have **two** `=` characters to pad it to length 16. Base64 strings have 0, 1 or 2 padding characters, depending on the input data  length.

Comment: then how come it decodes some of them for which has only one = character ?

Comment: @James: because those have one more character; they all have a length that's a multiple of 4 (including the `=`) padding character.

Comment: I see. Thank you. It looks like I removed a character "u" for all the data when I was filtering from my original source.

Answer (score 0):

Simple demonstration:

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: data = 'demonstration yo'

In [3]: code = base64.b64encode(data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 code = base64.b64encode(data)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dedup/lib/python3.8/base64.py:58, in b64encode(s, altchars)
     51 def b64encode(s, altchars=None):
     52     """Encode the bytes-like object s using Base64 and return a bytes object.
     53
     54     Optional altchars should be a byte string of length 2 which specifies an
     55     alternative alphabet for the '+' and '/' characters.  This allows an
     56     application to e.g. generate url or filesystem safe Base64 strings.
     57     """
---> 58     encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
     59     if altchars is not None:
     60         assert len(altchars) == 2, repr(altchars)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

In [4]: data = 'demonstration yo'.encode("ascii")

In [5]: code = base64.b64encode(data)

In [6]: code
Out[6]: b'ZGVtb25zdHJhdGlvbiB5bw=='

In [7]: base64.b64decode(code) == data
Out[7]: True

In [8]: base64.b64decode(code[0:18]) == data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 base64.b64decode(code[0:18]) == data

File ~/anaconda3/envs/dedup/lib/python3.8/base64.py:87, in b64decode(s, altchars, validate)
     85 if validate and not re.fullmatch(b'[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}', s):
     86     raise binascii.Error('Non-base64 digit found')
---> 87 return binascii.a2b_base64(s)

Error: Incorrect padding
```

What's cool:

It ignores extra padding.

```
In [13]: code
Out[13]: b'ZGVtb25zdHJhdGlvbiB5bw=='

In [14]: base64.b64decode(code + "=========".encode("ascii")) == data
Out[14]: True
```