# How to decode a RSA encrypted JWE in Python

Tags: python, jwt, rsa, jwe, pyjwt

I have JWE generated in Java using RSA keys. I want to decode this in python.
I tried PyJwt as in official documentation. But I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 209, in _load
    payload = base64url_decode(payload_segment)
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/utils.py", line 33, in base64url_decode
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input)
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "token_decrypt.py", line 37, in <module>
    decoded = jwt.decode(str_ex, private_key, algorithms=["RS256"])
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 119, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 95, in decode_complete
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 149, in decode_complete
    payload, signing_input, header, signature = self._load(jwt)
  File "/home/bhimasen/Documents/ENV/SysEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 211, in _load
    raise DecodeError("Invalid payload padding") from err
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid payload padding
```

This is the token that I have,

```
eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAtMjU2In0.oprppSvcEKs7gRLRitABobeciYtEOUTQwLli1j8JvCCU_BlbnBurjqqbjLNJR3IZcVDWW1zLfnwJ3vKRSxmuUCOfirmn9_u0UY2dUOMoRO9ubsmQzP2F-Prn7thBocUaeY44vSHBpzOSI78SYbN_jeKAI6Y5Lg4xYWWmIj2Y4VQDLrjKFyCe80y2p2HAj7jKgPTJvjwpxh3L0Bp0ukyVib5AUsg4X1fKRWmlvrTse46DfAt7Lb-nEjUQbIesmkwY8dL0_AebpR5tzwVkZZfyytLgqQ8kAqK7L5TXobNGXzIzXkh5L_NojCkroe3Z1Y3vWh-b2OBshDow10vckaHcoA.4FAuMJFgT_vqJnJc.LN-wCNcOYBwUMqPuiVVQNW8qCZ3wfLHKkzi9JaF27lUP-Er4GY9oVlhqCm6cZIyBNnSzucIknHg35zg-qHfktWvc8ZWnKrPSg2JF-lSgNVAislDj0jGJ2g_L3aHeGEXomCWgPTjyrhsW9QVYuVPbH6qLPNf4AwHDr4mnqO340KvI3PK_cro0HVcai701CTq9VhT-FPXEFg_q7ODBf3xE1ryzL7BO0lf-6qWpixbXv8PYbIffeihOQmbGzfizJy5mFdQsfcQKv_OXsCgErISjTKLANtPAJirDsZVrhPvWrHF6FdBmmVC8lEuwx2WV9RFkglQL5h3Zkvl2PV9Y5qvpIhHPLhiqbdAKIjW18Z1rQnByFa05pASduS15NvAyvCyfCLlkSgDPozBno6P8eHIjycT0WX5dA4wWFLR6yocKNmXLRBnQ6Yq7l3WYf6pBak6uo6t_A98Ra5VtOpWXyP9Y51s3x39sVSVlYLCT2EBbYcdVC1ZhRkbRDeal9z3K-nnjiyg8Fh9wTDERBpFCnrcRndbcgUzOHNkAvZWGkHTdWBkCc_dY8g18RvFcR64sbWA_GOzSMYWKD-JTaeamnN8Jtmj6ujRUEH34cZ7i9Ew_KKqwFt8teRx1aDi8hPEpINBrDsoIzc54Ta-_FyQ3zN6Cvs_L6k8B8n0XbTJycwmqNl20iCkHr4x138bR1oZLPxmq2muAypPnTZtvVCwZbzfS9cDTrk-jRh09aRaH1g2r6MT-PmESmFQoia_7TeKdoCA2agPl4NEcJz_3tUkHzjG6L-AU3XG9aQpha8zTlC3m0nPFwHPiA2WDnkxV-0VAynQ4gPiIqN6Kty5kEd895VNO8TE2fK7TlO_wQyHMsC3yaF9rWwiuBR471yDLEFK-SFPUhgP2rBFkF8qQ01vSI6XFfioAhkF7zHNRu9Ff.5ECWE_6VUAZQ4IIMOjhveA
```

And algorithm used for encryption is

```
{"cty":"JWT","enc":"A256GCM","alg":"RSA-OAEP-256"}
```

can anybody help how to solve this ?
or is there any approach that can make this decoding possible ?

Comment: Please post your most recent Python code along with test data so that a repro is possible.

Comment: Please also provide the `secret` used to encrypt the token, as we can't debug decoding without it (assuming this token is not 'valuable' if decoded).

Comment: pyjwt is not the right tool for this, it can only handle signed tokens (JWS) but not encrypted ones (JWE). But you have a JWE. Try using [Python-JOSE](https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwe/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT encrypting payload in python? (JWE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163000/jwt-encrypting-payload-in-python-jwe)

Comment: and btw. RSA is used for the signature here ("alg") and AES is used for content encyptryption ("enc").

Comment: @jps Thank you, I didnt know about Jose, I tried with Python-jose. It decrypts the JWE, but after that we need to decode. If I try the decrypted string in online base64decoder, I get the exact result, but if I use python's library base64 it gives, "Incorrect Padding" any idea ?

Comment: The strings in JWT/JWE are all Base64Url encoded. One difference to normal Base64 is the fact that padding is usually omitted. Even when you use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode` it still complains about padding. You might have to add padding manually like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729471/7329832) (or find a base64url decoder that works correctly)